# Como retornar variável global dentro de um classe RequestTask

Tags: android

Bom eu uso a classe RequestTask para fazer algumas coisas como:

- protected String doInBackground(String... uri)
- protected void onPostExecute(String result)

so que quero retorna as variáveis para fazer outras coisas fora da classe RequestTask, li algo sobre escopo de variáveis mais não sei como fazer.

Ex.:

```
public class Inicio_Activity ...{

// minha classe requesttask..
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

...meus comandos...

teste = "Pronto";

}

// declaro a string
String teste = "";

// Oncreate
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

new RequestTask().execute(http://www.asdasdas.com);

// digamos que tenho um textview que ira receber essa variável onde deveria aparecer "Pronto", como minha classe não retorna essa variável, não ira exibir nada.
texto1.setText(teste);

}
```

Comment: Veja só, quando se usa AsyncTask vc está dizendo que algo deve executar em uma Thread separada e que não sabe quando será finalizado. Já que vc espera um retorno e sua classe AsyncTask está dentro da Activity, crie uma variável estática que poderá ser usada entre as classes. Tenha em mente que vc nunca saberá quando a variável teste foi setada, pois vc não sabe quando a Thread vai ser finalizada!

Comment: ok coloquei static, no caso se eu chamar a variavel depois de chamar a classe AsyncTask, não esta me retornando nada, como vc falou que essa quase nao se sabe quando tera "resultado", como irei fazer pra quando ela tiver, que exiba esse resultado?

Comment: obs: testei aqui e está funcionando mas como vc falou.

abro o app: não exibe nada.
fecho e abro dnv: exibe corretamente a variável.

Comment: entendi agora, ele não exibe pq quando o chamei, a classe AsyncTask não tinha resultado, ai quando abro novamente ele é chamado e aparece, pq a classe já tem o resultado, agora so falta ver como vou esperar ele ter o resultado para prosseguir.

Comment: Basta migrar o `texto1.setText(...)` para o final do método `onPostExecute`. Garante que você já tem o resultado e está atualizando a `View` na `Main Thread`.

Comment: já tenho alguns comandos dentro do onPostExecute, mas minha ideia era pegar essa variável dentro do onCreate para ser usado em um BroadcastReceiver(exibido em uma notificação). o static ja ajudou mais em todo modo, quando o BroadcastReceiver for busca essa variável terá que encontrar algo..

Comment: A classe AsyncTask tem um método final get, não sei ao certo, mas parece que retorna o resultado após completar a tarefa. Vai ficar assim: `RequestTask rt = new RequestTask(); rt.execute(http://www.asdasdas.com); String retorno = rt.get();` **Lembrando que não testei. Peguei pela documentação oficial!**

Answer (score 1):

Você esta na frente de um maior problema de Android: o conceito do Async.
No contrario do iOS que autoriza bloquear o usuário, Android, com os sistema do Async, não permite.
Mesmo se você usa um variável global no Async, vai mudar pouca coisa porque o Async funciona de forma.... Async!
Significa que nada pode demonstrar que, quando você vai querer usar a variável global, ela vai ter o resultado que você esta esperando.

Tem 2 opções:

1) criar uma "CallBack" e fazer a totalidade do tratamento dentro do Async

2) Obrigar o Async a esperar (opção não bem no espírito Android!!)

Exemplo  de Callback com um HTTP Request:

```
public Biblio_HTTP(OnHttpTaskCompleted listener)
{
    super();
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    String text =null;
   <CUT>
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    listener.OnHttpTaskCompleted(result);    // Callback
}

// Def do Callback
public interface OnHttpTaskCompleted {

    void OnHttpTaskCompleted(String result);
}
}

  public class Callback implements Biblio_HTTP. OnHttpTaskCompleted {
    @Override

    public void OnHttpTaskCompleted(String result) {

        // Aqui vc faz o que vc quer com o resultado
    }
}
```

Exemplo 2 com um alert 'bloqueada":

```
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    try { Looper.loop(); }
    catch(RuntimeException e2) {}

    return resultado_alert;
```

Answer (score 0):

No construtor da RequestTask passe como parâmetro o TextView texto1, e no método onPostExecute(), coloque a linha de comando texto1.setText("seu texto").

Exemplo:

```
public RequestTask(TextView texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        texto1.setText("seu texto");
    }
```